# Retrofit2 with Kotlin: URL changes unexpectedly

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

Working on an Android project with Kotlin using Retrofit. Problem is that the URL changes unexpectedly and 422 is thrown.

More specifically, the problem is in the way Retrofit handles my formatted date. The API uses this time format:

```
2019-08-21T05%3A12%3A53Z
```

which, in this example, represents August 21, 2019, at 05:12:53. As you can see, the separator for time values is `%3A`.

This is the interface I'm using:

```
interface CurrenciesApi {

    @GET("currencies/sparkline?key=${apiKey}")
    fun getCurrenciesSparkline(
        @Query("start") start: String,
        @Query("end") end: String): Call<List<CurrencySparkline>>
}
```

**Minor remarks**: `apiKey` is a top-level constant properly imported. `CurrencySparkline` is a data class corresponding to the JSON response.

From previous unit tests I know Retrofit should be built this way

```
let myBaseUrl: String = "https:// ..."
let retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(myBaseUrl)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build()
```

implementation of `CurrenciesApi` interface

```
val api = retrofit.create(CurrenciesApi::class.java)
```

and lastly the call

```
val start = "2019-08-08T02%3A17%3A59Z"
val end = "2019-09-01T00%3A00%3A00Z"
response: Response<List<CurrencySparkline>> = api
    .getCurrenciesSparkline(start, end)
    .execute()
```

When testing the API endpoint in browser, the response is valid and data comes back. However, if I look at the URL in debug mode, I see that I has changed values for `start` and `end`:

```
... &start=2019-08-08T02%253A17%253A59Z&end=2019-09-01T00%253A00%253A00Z ...
```

Why is this happening and how do I fix it? Any sort of help is much appreciated.

Comment: use `@Query("query", encoded = true)` when using pre-urlencoded strings. Docs - Specifies whether the parameter name and value are already URL encoded.

Comment: Yes, this solved my problem. Thank you so much for your time and effort!!!